# Выбор MYSQL записи по нескольким строкам с группировкой по ID

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Приветствую.

Есть MySQL таблица со следующей структурой:

```
|id_a | id_b |  
|  1  |   1  |  
|  1  |   2  |  
|  1  |   3  |  
|  2  |   1  |  
|  2  |   4  |  
|  3  |   1  |
|  3  |   2  |
```

Есть необходимость сделать выборку id_a с фильтром сразу по нескольким значениям id_b.
Например нужно выбрать все id_a где id_b = 1 **И** 2, , т.е так, что бы на выходе мы получили id_a: 1, 3.
id_a - 2 нам не подходит т.к. у него **ЕСТЬ** id_b 1, но **НЕТ** id_b - 2, при этом нам подходит id_a - 1, т.к. у него есть оба значения id_b, пусть даже есть еще третье значение id_b - 3.

Запрос 
SELECT `id_a` FROM `table` WHERE `id_b` = 1 AND `id_b` = 2 GROUP BY `id_a`;
не подходит, т.к. в этом случае MySQL ищет что бы в одной строке было сразу оба значения id_b.
Есть идея сделать через GROUP_CONCAT объединив `id_b` в одну строку.
Например

```
|id_a | id_b |  
|  1  |   1, 2, 3  |  
|  2  |   1, 4     |  
|  3  |   1,2      |
```

Но в таком случае придется делать запрос, в запросе, что значительно повысит нагрузку на СУБД при выборке, чего допускать не желательно.

Буду благодарен любой Вашей помощи.

Comment: Вам where не нужно. просто id_a  и group_concat, посмотрите примеры использования group_concat

Comment: `id_b in(1,2) group by id_a having count(1)=2` собственно описано по ссылке выше

Comment: @Mike спасибо за помощь, это решило проблему!

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать такой запрос без группировки:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id_a
FROM test t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id_a FROM test WHERE id_b = 1) t2
     ON t1.id_a = t2.id_a
WHERE t1.id_b = 2
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8d86/4)

Вывод: `1, 2`.

Answer (score 1):

и будет вам счастье

```
SELECT id_a FROM table WHERE id_b in (1, 2) GROUP BY id_a;
```

Comment: счастье, которое выведет `1, 2, 3`.

Comment: тогда group_concat как вам сказали уже выше :select GROUP_CONCAT( cr_id) from cardread
where cr_id in (1,2,3)